# Create new Cell in existing excel file and export data from output - Selenium_TestNG_JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have a big problem. I would like to create a new field named "Names" in the existing excel file and save the search results for items in this field. I'm tired of this for a long time. Please, help. My code looks like this:

```
enter code hereList<WebElement> resultsOfFinding = driver.findElements(By.className("vip"));
    int FindingElements = resultsOfFinding.size();
    System.out.println(FindingElements);
    //Loop for get names of iphones
    for (int i = 0; i < resultsOfFinding.size(); i++) {
        String names = resultsOfFinding.get(i).getText();
        System.out.println(names);
        FileInputStream files1 = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Porczykwas\\Desktop\\Rzeczy" +
                "\\SeleniumKsiazka\\importTestNg (1) (1).xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook1 = new XSSFWorkbook(files1);
        XSSFSheet sheet1 = workbook1.getSheetAt(0);

        Cell cell = sheet1.createRow(0).createCell(3[enter image description here][1]);
        cell.setCellValue("Names");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Porczykwas\\Desktop\\Rzeczy" +
                "\\SeleniumKsiazka\\importTestNg (1).xlsx"));
        workbook1.write(out);
```

in the attachment, view the excel file before and after running the script

Comment: what does this have to do with [tag:selenium] and [tag:testng] ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take an example..

Create a Cell
You need to create a row before creating a cell. A row is nothing but a collection of cells.

The following code snippet is used for creating a cell.

```
//create new workbook
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 

//create spreadsheet with a name
XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("new sheet");

//create first row on a created spreadsheet
XSSFRow row = spreadsheet.createRow(0);

//create first cell on created row
XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
```

For Referene please visit the site below for more information

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi/apache_poi_cells.htm